# After npm run build only few images in dist folder

Tags: image, vue.js, npm, npm-run

When I run my vue.js project in dev mode, all images are loaded properly but after npm run build, some images are missing because they are not in the generated dist folder.

Some images got transfered but not all. I don't get the reason why the images which are in the dist folder are in the folder and the others not. Anybody an idea what could be the reason for this problem?

This is my **webpack.confi.js** file

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
```

This is the **html** file

```
<img src="/static/img/name.883d0fb.png" id="name">
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant code for at least *1* image file that is **not** included, and also the relevant code for at least *1* image that **is** included.

Comment: Have you changed the webpack configuration created with Vue cli ?